# Order by a field, starting by a letter

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-order-by

How could I get those records ordered by a field starting by a letter?

For example, I have this values in a field:

```
TABLE: mytable
ROW: myrow
ROW
-----
A
B
C
D
```

=> ORDER BY ROW STARTING FROM LETTER 'C'

I want to get this query result

```
ROW
-----
C
D
A
B
```

### Solution by @sagi

```
SELECT * FROM mytable
ORDER BY CASE WHEN myrow >= 'C' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END DESC,
     myrow ASC
```

Comment: After `'C'`, why `D,A,B` why not `D,B,A`? What is the rule for the rest of the rows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with `CASE EXPRESSION` like this:

```
SELECT * FROM YourTable
ORDER BY CASE WHEN YourColumn >= 'C' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END DESC,
         YourColumn ASC
```

Comment: This will only work when you have all in upper case. Remember, sorting of alphabets depends on their **ASCII** values.

Comment: That is correct, but by the data he posted I assumed thats default for all of his data. @LalitKumarB